# Take screenshot with Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub google()
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "www.google.com"
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            Application.SendKeys "({1068})", True
            DoEvents
        Loop
        AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Dim shp As Shape
        With ActiveSheet
            Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        End With
        shp.Height = 600
        shp.Width = 800
        .Document.Forms(0).Submit
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

I am using this code to take screenshot using Excel VBA Macro. However, this code is taking a screenshot of my whole screen. I need the screenshot of a webpage alone. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> takes a screenshot of the entire desktop. To take a screenshot of the current application window use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>.

```
Application.SendKeys "%{1068}", True
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It is working. I also have an issue with the same code. It is taking the screenshot of the webpage before it is loaded completely. So, I got the screenshot of a empty webpage.. How can I correct this?

Comment: The loop in your code should already wait for the page to be loaded. Unless there's code in the page that continues loading stuff after the page itself has already completed loading. I don't know of a generic way to wait for the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking out for the solution to fix the issue. If you  find anything, please let me know. Thanks in advance.